# Fetching a URL From the init() func in Go on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, spreadsheet, mux

**Background**: I'm running Go on GAE and using Mux for my router. In order to fetch a URL GAE requires that I use its built in urlFetch capability. I want to make this URL fetch happen during my modules init() but as far as I can tell I can only use urlFetch when invoked via a handler.

```
func init() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)
  r.HandleFunc("/about", anotherHandler)
  http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

GAE suggests the following code for making a urlFetch:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
client := urlfetch.Client(c)
```

... but its argument is an http router, and it doesn't want to work if I pass my mux router. So I'm out of ideas of how to make this urlFetch happen outside the scope of a URL handler.

Error when passing the mux router: "cannot use r (type *mux.Router) as type *http.Request in argument to "appengine".NewContext"

Comment: _"... but its argument is an http router..."_ It's not an http router, it's an `*http.Request` so obviously you can't pass a `*mux.Router` value.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use AppEngine services that require a [`Context`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Context) outside of handlers (because the creation of a `Context` requires an [`*http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) value). This by nature means you can't use them in package `init()` functions either.
<sub>Note that you can use them from cron jobs and tasks added to task queues, because tasks and cron jobs are executed by issuing HTTP GET requests.</sub>

You have to restructure your code so that the service (urlFetch in your case) gets called from a handler.

A possible solution is to check if init completed in handlers that serve user requests. If not, perform the initialization function you would otherwise put in `init()` before proceeding to serve the request.

Yes, this may cause first requests to take considerably longer to serve. For this purpose (to avoid this) I recommend you to utilize [Warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Warmup_requests). A warmup request is issued to a new instance before it goes "live", before it starts serving user requests. In your `app.yaml` config file you can enable warmup requests by adding `-warmup` to the `inbound_services` directive:

```
inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

This will cause the App Engine infrastructure to first issue a `GET` request to `/_ah/warmup`. You can register a handler to this URL and perform initialization tasks. As with any other request, you will have an [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) in the warmup handler.

But please note that:

> ..you may encounter [loading requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Loading_Requests), even if warmup requests are enabled in your app.

Which means that in rare cases it may happen a new instance will not receive a warmup request, so its best to check initialization state in user handlers too.

Comment: Rock on, thanks Icza ! Super helpful, Warmup requests are right on the money.