# Issue http request google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am writing code in my application that given a URL I would like GAE to return me the response body to the GET request, I can't seem to find a simple way to do this. I have read through their documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/issue-requests) and this is the code I currently have

```
func Extract(url string) ([]string, error) {
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("", url, nil)
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Do(r)
...
}
```

but every time I run this code I'm getting the following error

```
NewContext passed an unknown http.Request
```

I guess how do I make that `http.Request` known?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine services that require a [`Context`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Context) can only be used from handlers because the creation of a `Context` requires an [`*http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) value. But this `Request` must be the *incoming* request (to your app), not an *outgoing* request you want to make.

So you need a handler, which has an `http.Request` parameter, you have to pass *that* to the context creation:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    r2, _ := http.NewRequest("", url, nil)
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Do(r2)
    // ...
}
```

See related question: [Fetching a URL From the init() func in Go on AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912318/fetching-a-url-from-the-init-func-in-go-on-appengine)

Comment: is there a way to make an outgoing request?